# display data in oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a SQL query from Oracle and want to display the name, but unfortunately, it won't display as I wanted.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  first_table A,
  second_table B
WHERE
  A.FULL_NAME = B.FULL_NAME
  AND A.FULL_NAME LIKE '%name%'
```

The `$name` is something like 'George Harrison'.

Comment: please post some sample data and desired result

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your query. The `$` is missing near `%name%`

Change from

```
'%name%'
```

Into

```
'%$name%'
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, that's the whole query.

Comment: I was mean to see PHP code, May be `$name` is not passing correctly to query.

Answer (score 0):

Like operator is Case Sensitive. If you don't know case of FULL_NAME convert it to upper or lower .

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM first_table A, second_table B 
   WHERE A.FULL_NAME = B.FULL_NAME 
   AND Lower(A.FULL_NAME) LIKE '%name%'
```

now pass name in lower case and try.

Comment: Hi Hadesh, Will try this one. Thanks